# JavaScript Toggle Classes Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm building out a sidebar navigation in a Rails app and naturally need to use some JS to allow for the submenu to the sidebar. I have it so that it mostly works using jQuery in terms of applying the right styling and works on other pages (but not the home page and that's a separate issue). What I'm trying to figure out is how to write the code in regular JS instead of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('col-lg-2 col-md-2');
    $('#dash-wrapper').toggleClass('col-lg-11').removeClass('col-lg-9');
    $('#sidebar').toggle();
 });

});
```

My thought was to put on my link an onclick function and reference it to the following code:

```
function sideSwitch (){
  var side = document.getElementById('sidebarCollapse');
  var dash = document.getElementById('dash-wrapper');
  var bar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
  bar.classList.toggle('active').toggle('col-lg-2 col-md-2');
  dash.classList.toggle('col-lg-11').removeClass('col-lg-9');
  bar.toggle();
}
```

On my link I have:

```
<%=link_to image_tag('products.png') + 'Products', '/', class: 'nav-link d-flex align-items-center flex-column sidebar side-links', id: 'sidebarCollapse', data: { toggle: 'collapse', target: '#submenu'}, :onclick => 'sideSwitch()'%>
```

This does not work. It's not triggering.

Comment: no line of code from `sideSwitch()` is being executed?

Comment: classList's `toggle` method returns true/false, you can't chain them. Also `removeClass` is not a method of classList, use `remove` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods

Comment: also, I don't think you can call `bar.toggle()`, `toggle` doesn't look like a valid Element method, translating from jquery to vanilla javascript is not just changing the selectors, you have to use valid vanilla javascript methods too...

Comment: you should have some errors popping on the browser's console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure javascript implementation of toggle and toggleClass

```
function toggle(ele,className){

   if(!className){
     ele.style.display = ele.style.display === "" ? "none" : ""; 
     return;
   }
   if(ele.classList.contains(className)){
      ele.classList.remove(className);
   }else{
        ele.classList.add(className);
   }
}

function sideSwitch(){
   var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
   var dashWrapper = document.getElementById('dash-wrapper');
   toggle(sidebar,'active');
   toggle(sidebar,'col-lg-2');
   toggle(sidebar,'col-md-2');
   toggle(dashWrapper,'col-lg-11');
   toggle(dashWrapper,'col-lg-9');
   toggle(dashWrapper);

}
```